# How to find errors in rdlc xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, rdlc

I am  new to xslt.
Below is a xml fragment from a rdlc report.
I would like to write a xsl transformation that tells me about cases where the "Field" attribute "Name" is not equal to the "DataField" child element.
In the sample below that would be the last field (Name="Url").

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
    <DataSets>
        <DataSet Name="TestReportModel">              
            <Fields>
                <Field Name="Name">
                    <DataField>Name</DataField>
                    <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="Description">
                    <DataField>Description</DataField>
                    <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
                </Field>
                <Field Name="Url">
                    <DataField>DataFieldDoesNotMatchAttribute</DataField>
                    <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
                </Field>
            </Fields>
        </DataSet>
    </DataSets>
</Report>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the stylesheet below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:def="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition"
    xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="def rd">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="def:Report/def:DataSets/def:DataSet/def:Fields/def:Field[@Name != def:DataField]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="def:Field">
        <Field>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <DataField><xsl:value-of select="def:DataField"/></DataField>
            <xsl:copy-of select="rd:TypeName"/>
        </Field>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Tested with Chrome and Firefox, seems to work with both. 
Great.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find an answer helpful or the most helpful, please click the check mark on the left to make it appear green (below the arrowheads). This way, it will be marked as the accepted answer.